# How to specify the angular version while creating ionic application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develop an application using Mobilefirst with Ionic framework. I found that this application uses angular-5. But I know only AngularJS. Is there any command to specify the angular version while creating ionic app.

Comment: Angular 2+ is used in ionic 2+ applications. It's easy to learn angular 2 and its very is to migrate from angularjs to angular.
If you really really need to go with angularjs you have to use ionic 1.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to install Ionic 1 for your AngularJS development you can use npm to choose that version like this:

```
npm install -g ionic@1.4.0
```

If you want to get the old docs you can do that [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1) but I really think you should try and upgrade to angular2+ and use the latest ionic. You can learn more about migrating to angular2 [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use AngularJS for your ionic development, then you need to start your project with the flag ionic1, choose template

```
ionic start myProjectName --type ionic1
```

move into the project and run

```
ionic serve
```

---

Already done the above steps but wanted to Choose specific version:
If you wanted to use a sepcific version of AngularJS v1, within your project directory simply update your bower.json.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.10",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.10"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any command to specify the angular version while creating ionic app.

**Run from your project root folder:** `ionic info`

```
C:\Users\Training\myApp>ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Training\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v9.3.0
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : D:\Setups\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

**If you want to create new project in ionic 1 then use:**

```
ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1
```